# RIPEMD-160 vs SHA-256

Tags: sha, ripemd

Can anyone shed some light into SHA-256 and RIPEMD-160, which algorithm is normally faster and what are the performance and space comparisons, if any?
By space comparisons I don't mean 160 bits and 256 bits, but what are the collisions frequency, difference in space requirements in production env. and time to calculate both.
Is RIPEMD-160 a requirement for European countries?
Any additional information, that would be helpful in deciding.

Answer (score 1):

As for SHA-256 there are no known collisions. I believe that while some advances have been made in generating collisions in SHA-1 faster than brute force, that those are still not practical and certainly not applicable for SHA-256.

I'm not very familiar with RIPEMD-160 so I cannot say much about it.

Answer (score 1):

`RIPMD-160` can be used to any message size while `SHA` is limited to `2^64-1`.
and `RIPMD-160` takes 160 steps during the process whereas `SHA` takes only 80.
as I think `RIPMD-160` is better.

Comment: Round count doesn't indicate "better".  If anything you could say that as SHA256's digest size is greater than RIPEMD-160's it *may* indicate a higher resilience to collisions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is RIPEMD-160 a requirement for European countries?

No.